# Terminal command/executable only works in one directory and errors out in any other directory

Tags: java, linux, unix, terminal, scheme

I just installed Kawa to code some scheme, https://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/index.html.

I'm using MacOs Terminal (my Mac is currently using Big Sur).

I cloned the repo, and followed all the installation steps specified in here: https://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Source-distribution.html

Also installed dependencies.

The command that starts the program is "Kawa".

Everything works fine if, and only if, I type "Kawa" command in terminal *when I'm *in the directory that all the files where copied into**. The program runs and I'm able to code in scheme. Please note that this is not a local executable, as I don't have to type "./Kawa" for it to work.

However, if I'm in any other directory and I type "Kawa", the following Error gets printed on the console: **Could not find or load main class kawa.repl
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kawa.repl**

I'm just learning about unix/linux and don't know much about java, but I'm guessing this has something to do with file paths?

I checked and some of the files were installed in /usr/local/share/kawa in my Mac. If you go through the installation steps that I linked to above, after you run "make install", it says that you have to manually specify:

CLASSPATH=$PREFIX/share/java/kawa.jar

export CLASSPATH

I don't know exactly what that does. I wonder if this is something that I should put in some file, I tried just typing in the terminal and running the "kawa" command after with no success.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You've replaced $PREFIX by /user/local when you tried the commands, right? The script launching Kawa needs to be find the java classes if you're not in the folder. Do read on classpath in Java as this is critical to get Java programs to run.

Comment: @JPMoresmau Thank you very much for your response. I didn't replace it with the path, but I just did it now and it didn't work. Because you mentioned, I searched a bit for class path in java, and I ended up changing the PATH (not CLASSPATH) env variable to see if it would solve. Basically no commands would work anymore lol. Had to close and reopen terminal for it to go back to normal. Thanks for the help, lookin up CLASSPATH to see if I can fix it.